# Remove UILocalNotification when cell is removed containing date

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

i am making reminder application there is table view and there is dates in cell and when that cell date become todays day UILocalNotification fires. for that i am using following code

```
-(void)notification {

    // logic for local notification start

    NSDateFormatter *Form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Form setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    for (int i=0;i<_convertedBdates.count;i++)
    {
        NSDate *date =[Form dateFromString:[_convertedBdates objectAtIndex:i ]];
        //     NSLog(@"date%@",date);

        if(notification)
        {
            notification.fireDate = date;
            notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Today is %@\'s Birthday",[_combinedNameArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            notification.alertAction = @"View";

            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }
    // local notification logic ends here   

}
```

now i have also implemented functionality of deleting cell from table view 
now my problem is cell gets removed but its notification not there is no cell but when that date comes then notification fire.

how should i remove that particular notification when that cell is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: My initial answer was wrong, because I didn't realize that the OS copies `UILocalNotification`s when you schedule them, rather than just retaining them. So...

There are two ways to do this, as far as I can tell.

- Cancel all notifications when a row is deleted, and then reschedule the remaining ones.

This is going to be more efficient if you don't have many notifications scheduled, and it will definitely be much easier to code. (Note: I don't know enough about the low-level things at work to say which is necessarily more efficient, but my guess is that the difference isn't really important.)

Whenever a row is deleted, simply call

```
[[UIApplcation sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Then update `_convertedBDates` appropriately, and finally call your `notification` method again to reschedule new local notifications for those events that are still around.

- Create unique identifiers for your local notifications

This is possibly the more efficient way, if you can come up with a good way to make those unique identifiers and if you have a lot of notifications scheduled. (Emphasis on *possibly*). One possibility is to use the time at which the notification will fire, if you can guarantee that no two notifications will fire at the same time. Other possibilities are the label for the notification (again if you can be sure of uniqueness). Whatever you decide to use for your unique identifier, you can store it by adding this outside your for loop:

```
self.uniqueIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

(where uniqueIDArray is an `NSMutableArray* @property` of your class) and then this right before you schedule the notification:

```
[uniqueIDArray addObject:whateverObjectYouUseForTheUniqueID];
notification.userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:whateverObjectYouUseForTheUniqueID
                                                      forKeys:@"uniqueID"];
```

Then, in whatever method you're using to delete the cells, you would do something like this:

```
uniqueIDToDelete = [self.uniqueIDArray objectAtIndex:indexOfCellBeingDeleted];
NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledNotifications];
UILocalNotification *notifToDelete;
for (UILocalNotification *notif in scheduledNotifications) {
    if ([[notif.userInfo objectForKey:@"uniqueID"] isEqual:uniqueIDToDelete]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notif];
    }
}
[self.uniqueIDArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexOfCellBeingDeleted];
```

Comment: can you demonstrate this please with some example ?

Comment: its just 2 month i have started iphone so except cancellocalnotification everything is unclear im sorry

Comment: thank you so much for spending your time for some stranger salute to you

Comment: No problem. If answers are helpful, even if they don't end up resolving your issue, please consider upvoting them.

Comment: i cant up vote i dont have enough points for that :( but i have accepted ur answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use cell as source for notification. Use data model instead. Also you could remove notification easily

**UPDATE**

```
Model *model = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; model.notificationID = // here you store created notification identifier

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] // contains all local notifications, you should search you need by ID and remove it using cancelLocalNotification method.
```

P.S. notification ID you can store in notification userInfo

Comment: i am nood can you give some example please i am using array of dates same array i use for table view

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
> NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
> UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath];
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notif];
> ```